# XC_RESOURCE (RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY: high watermark memory limit exceeded) (limit=2098 MB)

Tags: ios, flutter, crash

Flutter 3.3.9,
Device iphone 16.4.1
Android Studio Tested
Xcode Tested

Getting this error when i run App on real device ios 16.4.1 on the splash screen after 2 sec App crashed and got XC_RESOURCE (RESOURCE_TYPE_MEMORY: high watermark memory limit exceeded) (limit=2098 MB) and when i ran App from Xcode i got "Terminated due to memory issue"
Your suggestions and help will be appreciated.
Thank You.

I tried to run on Physical Device on Iphone but getting Crash due to memory Issue
just want to solve this issue

Comment: also started to get this error today.

Comment: no, only solution i found to run it on release mode.